# How to get the cursor of each entity in a App Engine datastore query without performance hit?

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, objectify, datastore, database-cursor

I have a Datastore query using cursor (Objectify v5) and I want to get the cursor after each item in the result list. Code looks like this:

```
public List<Puzzle> queryWithCursor(String cursor, String order, int limit) {
  Query<Puzzle> query = ObjectifyService.ofy()
    .load()
    .type(Puzzle.class)
    .order(order)
    .limit(limit);
  query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursor));
  List<Puzzle> puzzles = new ArrayList<>();
  QueryResultIterator<Puzzle> iterator = query.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Puzzle puzzle = iterator.next();
    puzzle.setCursor(iterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString());
    puzzles.add(puzzle);
  }
  return puzzles;
}
```

While the method works correctly, it triggers so many Datastore queries behind the scene. Basically, every time iterator.getCursor() runs, it triggers an additional query. I learnt from Stackdriver Trace that if limit is 20, the method triggers 19 queries in total (it seems that the last .getCursor() does not trigger additional query). So this method is even slower and more costly than the similar query using offset.

Is this really a bug? Is there a way to avoid the performance hit?

Comment: Getting the cursor at every iteration seems an unusual thing to be doing - this might be a case where a different question, asking about what you want to achieve, could get you more helpful answers

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for replying. I think you're right about providing more context. I have 2 screens: PuzzleList and PuzzleDetail. PuzzleList shows a list of puzzles and when clicking on a puzzle, it opens PuzzleDetail. From PuzzleDetail, there is a Next button to go directly to the next unsolved puzzle. That's why I need cursor for each puzzle in the PuzzleList so I can implement the Go Next feature.

Currently I use offset instead of cursor in the query but it's too costly due to the insanely high number of Read operations.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understood your question, but, is there any reason that makes you believe that it should make less queries? According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Cursor), it resumes a query from a position defined by the cursor, so it will be a new API call and that's why it appears on Stackdriver. If I misunderstood your question, please let me know.

Comment: @Hieu you can pass the 'order' you use to the Detail page, and then use that to construct the appropriate query: for 'next' - 'ORDER by $orderField WHERE $orderField > currentItem.$orderField LIMIT 1' (and < for previous)

Comment: Hi Greg, that doesn't work for me since I want to return the next "unsolved" puzzle, i.e. I have to keep going down the list until having found some puzzle the current user has not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a fundamental behavior of the datastore, at least in the old sdk (as opposed to the new sdk that Objectify 6 uses, which may be the same maybe not). Calling getCursor() at non-batch boundaries restarts the query. You can try it with the low-level API.

There is a workaround: Make up your own Cursor class. It should consist of the low level Cursor and an offset. Explicitly set a `chunk()` size, then your cursor should consist of the `Cursor` at index 0 plus an offset into the chunk.

Then when you want to restart a query at that cursor, use `.cursor(batchStartCursor).offset(offsetIntoBatch)`.

Comment: Awesome, this answers my question perfectly. Thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.SortDirection;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultList;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ListPeopleServlet extends HttpServlet {

  static final int PAGE_SIZE = 15;
  private final DatastoreService datastore;

  public ListPeopleServlet() {
    datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
  }

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(PAGE_SIZE);

    // If this servlet is passed a cursor parameter, let's use it.
    String startCursor = req.getParameter("cursor");
    if (startCursor != null) {
      fetchOptions.startCursor(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(startCursor));
    }

    Query q = new Query("Person").addSort("name", SortDirection.ASCENDING);
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

    QueryResultList<Entity> results;
    try {
      results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // IllegalArgumentException happens when an invalid cursor is used.
      // A user could have manually entered a bad cursor in the URL or there
      // may have been an internal implementation detail change in App Engine.
      // Redirect to the page without the cursor parameter to show something
      // rather than an error.
      resp.sendRedirect("/people");
      return;
    }

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter w = resp.getWriter();
    w.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    w.println("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">");
    w.println("<title>Cloud Datastore Cursor Sample</title>");
    w.println("<ul>");
    for (Entity entity : results) {
      w.println("<li>" + entity.getProperty("name") + "</li>");
    }
    w.println("</ul>");

    String cursorString = results.getCursor().toWebSafeString();

    // This servlet lives at '/people'.
    w.println("<a href='/people?cursor=" + cursorString + "'>Next page</a>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really answer my question. What I want is a cursor after each item in the list, not just one cursor at the end of the list.